# How to identify truncated columns in SQL Server 2016

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have been experimenting using the code below and it seems it does not work.

```
DBCC TRACEON (460); 

DECLARE @aa as TABLE (name varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @aa
SELECT '1234567890'
```

**Error**

> String or binary data would be truncated

**Expected error:**

> String or binary data would be truncated in table @aa, column name. Truncated value: '1234567890'

According to https://www.procuresql.com/blog/2018/09/26/string-or-binary-data-get-truncated/ SQL Sever 2019 will be able to identify the columns that have been truncated, but can be used in SQL Server 2016 using **TRACEON 460**.

In terms of roles, I have "public", "processadmin", and "sysadmin".

In the sys.messages I think the patch for this feature based on message_id=2628:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message_id | text                                                                                                 |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2628       | String or binary data would be truncated in table '%.*ls', column '%.*ls'. Truncated value: '%.*ls'. |
| 8152       | String or binary data would be truncated.                                                            |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Details:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard (64-bit)
Version : 13.0.5149.0
Is Clustered : False
Is HADR Enabled : False
Is XTP Supported : True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new error message hasn't yet been back-ported to SQL Server 2016. From [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/) (emphasis mine):

> This new message is also backported ... (**and in an upcoming SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU**) ...

This CU has not been delivered yet. The most recent, CU5 (13.0.5264.1), was released in January and did not include it.

And just a small correction, you need to opt in to this behavior (via the trace flag) **even in the SQL Server 2019 CTPs**. The reason is that a different error number is produced, and this could break existing applications and unit tests that behave based on the error number raised. This will be documented as a breaking change when SQL Server 2019 is released, but I'm sure it will still bite some people when they upgrade.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for providing clear details with regards to the matter, too bad I badly need this feature now.     Regardless, I think they should have taken the backward compatibility hit on SQL Sever 2019 and not require traceon.  I dont think unit test error numbers are that significant compared to the overall benefit as unit test should be corrected whenever production db moved to a higher version.  And with my kind of thinking I think I would not be a good DBA. lol

Comment: @Earl it won't require the trace flag by release, I'm just commenting on the current state.